# How to get data attribute of each elements from the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, jquery-data

I have this "list":

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="test" data-id="1"></div>
    <div class="test" data-id="2"></div>
    <div class="test" data-id="3"></div>
    <div class="test" data-id="4"></div>
    <div class="test" data-id="5"></div>
</div>
```

i need to get `data` attribute of all elements, so i do this:

```
var _this = $('.list'),
    _el = _this.find('div');

var _id = $.map(_el, function(el) {
    return {name: 'offer-id', value: $(el).data('id')}
});
```

but what i get is only attribute of first element... What is wrong? Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4DRxz/

Comment: Well, in your demo you are only *accessing* the value of the first element. What else did you expect from running `alert(_id[0].value)`?

Comment: If i do this using each method i have the same result...

Comment: Then the way you are calling each might be wrong, because `_id` looks good to me: http://jsfiddle.net/4DRxz/1/

Comment: ok but how to get only a value of this?

Comment: Replace the `alert` in your fiddle with `console.log(_id);` and check your console. You'll see the array with 5 elements in it. Your code is fine as far as I can tell.

Comment: *"how to get only a value of this"* Not sure what you mean. `_id` is an array. You can access the value you want with `_id[<index>].value`.  You can use a loop to iterate over the array.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not exhibit the problem the OP describes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/), the map function will return you an array with the mapped elements. You can iterate over them if you need each one. 
Like:

```
for(var i=0; i<_id.length; i++){
   // do stuff with _id[i].value here
}
```

or by using `$.each` as suggested by another answer.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4DRxz/3/)